# Accessing POST params with same name in python

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine

I need to get values of these check boxes with same name through HTTP "POST".

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dde" name="dept[]" value="dde"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="dre" name="dept[]" value="dre"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="iid" name="dept[]" value="iid"/>
```

How to get these values in python using self.request.get() method?

Comment: Add a little more context to your question, what standard library module or framework are you using? Can you add a little sample code to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `request.get_all()`.

According to [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get_all) it  "Returns a list of values of all of the query (URL) or POST arguments with the given name, possibly an empty list."